# Continuity of $|x|^y$ at $(0,0)$

Tags: calculus, continuity

How do I prove or disprove whether the function $f(x,y)=|x|^y$ is continuous or discontinuous at $(0,0)$. Using epsilon delta definition.

To disprove it I tried taking examples like $y=mx^k$ and then tested the limit of function at $x=0$ but didn't reach anywhere.

Comment: $0^0$ is undefined or undeterminate (except in some particular context where a finite value is conventionally attributed in well specified conditions). When both $x$ and $y$  tend to $0$ there is no unique limite for $|x|^y$ : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14709220/Zero-puissance-zero-Zero-to-the-Zero-th-Power pp.7-11.

Comment: Hint: for any $\delta>0$, $f(\delta,0)=1$ but $f(0,\delta)=0$. So take $\varepsilon=\frac13$. Now assume $f(0,0)=a$ for some $a$, and you should be able to show that $f$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a > 0$ be any given positive number.  If you take these sequences:
$$
x_n = \frac{1}{n},\qquad y_n = \frac{-\log a}{\log n}
$$
then you get, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
x_n \to 0,
\\
y_n \to 0,
\\
x_n^{y_n} \to a.
$$

Answer (score 1):

This function is not continuous.

Suppose that it is, and that the limit is $L$. Then, along the curve $y=0$, the function is identically $1$, and thus $L=1$. Similarly, along the curve $x=0$, the function is identically $0$, and thus $L=0$. These two results form a contradiction. Thus $f$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$.

Comment: Can't we show it using $\epsilon,\delta$  definition?

Comment: Usually epsilon delta is used to prove that a function *is* continuous. To prove it isn't continuous is a lot easier (most of the time!) and is just exhibiting a counterexample. Of course, using epsilon delta is doable, by assuming that it does converge to some limit $L$, then using epsilon delta on that, along with finding points arbitrarily close to the origin with very different values of $f$... sound familiar? That's because the simplest epsilon delta solution is virtually identical to mine.